# S3 Cross account replication not replicate the files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, replication, amazon-iam

i have the following configuration and I've already tried a lot of things. Can someone check it an say what might be the issue? 
I've added the canonical account of the source to the destination bucket.
The replication is enabled on the source bucket. Is replicating the whole bucket.

Source bucket.

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "PutObjPolicy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyUnEncryptedObjectUploads",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::source-bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "true"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AWSSourcebucketWrite20131101",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::external_account_who_write_the_files:root",
                    "arn:aws:iam::external_account_who_write_the_files:root",
                    "arn:aws:iam::external_account_who_write_the_files:root"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::source-bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Destination bucket

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "PutObjPolicy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyUnEncryptedObjectUploads",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::source-bucket-replication/*",
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "true"
                },
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:SecureTransport": "true"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt123",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::source_bucket_account:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ReplicateObject",
                "s3:ReplicateDelete"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::source-bucket-replication/*",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:SecureTransport": "true"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried adding new file to your source bucket? Or update an existing file on source bucket? I think replication takes effect only on the items added or updated after enabling replication.

Comment: Sure, I tried. Added new and updated already uploaded files too. Without any success